# How can to launch the Mail app from within my app?

Tags: iphone, url, email, uiimage, photo

**How do I launch the iPhone Mail app (***with a Photo attachment***) from within my app?** (Photo is a UIImage in my app).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MFMailComposeViewController is what you want, which was introduced with iPhone OS 3.0.

https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MailComposer/index.html
http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-in-app-email

This blog post also covers adding UIImage attachments:

http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/2009/07/how-to-make-your-iphone-app-send-email-with-attachments/

Comment: I studied the sample code from Apple. It uses the MFMailComposeViewController. But I'd like to directly use the mail app instead and load it with a photo (like the photo app does). How can I do this?

Comment: The third link that I included shows how to attach a photo to the email.

Comment: Using the MFMailComposeViewController does pop up the standard email sending screen the same way the Apple apps do when emailing something like a photo.